# Add minor data labels for date x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeline

Considering the example data below:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("HFK", "AMW", "OPS", "QTM", "RKL", 
  "PDF", "CAD", "PMC", "NLY", "TWV"), Date = structure(c(18659, 19024, 
  19052, 19052, 19079, 19153, 19192, 19233, 19260, 19417), 
  class = "Date"), Value = c("121 M", "105 M", "90 M", "93 M", 
  "25 M", "56 M", "89 M", "121 M", "81 M", "50 M"), displ = 
  c(1, 0.45, 0.25, 0.75, 1, 0.50, 0.85, 0.25, 0.75, 1)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to draw a timeline with ggplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, displ, label = Name)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic() + guides(color = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "MY TITLE") +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold",
          margin = margin(c(0.3,0,-1.7,0), unit = "in")), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, color = "black",
           margin = margin(c(0.05,0,0,0), unit = "in"), face = "bold"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.9)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_minor_breaks = "1 month", 
              date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,1.7)) + geom_label() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = Date, xend = Date,
                   y = 0, yend = displ), size = 0.5)
```

[image]

I want to add the months to the plot as well, as a minor data label. but the only way I saw was using:

```
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_minor_breaks = "1 month", 
              date_labels = "%b-%Y") +
```

But that repeats the year for every months. I ant each month and year to be mentioned only once as a timeline. The desired output is:

[image]

Comment: Your code cannot be run. There is a variable `displ` but your `df` does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your example (no `displ` column in the data frame `df`). However, we can create one for demonstration purposes easily enough by doing

```r
df$displ <- as.numeric(substr(df$Value, 1, 2)) / 100
```

Although there are ways to fake nested axes using facets, this becomes difficult with dates, and it may be best simply to label the axis with months and add the years as annotations:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Date, displ, label = Name)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic() + guides(color = 'none') +
  labs(title = "MY TITLE") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 1.7)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = Date, xend = Date,
                   y = 0, yend = displ), size = 0.5) +
  geom_label(fill = 'white') +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob('2021'), ymin = -0.15, ymax = -0.15,
                    xmin = as.Date('2021-02-28'), xmax = as.Date('2021-02-28')) +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob('2022'), ymin = -0.15, ymax = -0.15,
                    xmin = as.Date('2022-02-28'), xmax = as.Date('2022-02-28')) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(30, 10, 10, 10)),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan, I actually need this to be automated no matter what the data is. the way the position of the annotations are entered are manual and if the data changes, it wont be accurate